# why selection of a cell in one section affect to cells in other sections in iOS tableview, objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I have a tableview with three sections.each section has different number of cells. What I want is to set the user can select only one cell(any cell) from all cells in the first section, and should be able to select another one cell(any cell) from the second section and as well as from section three. in my case if I select one cell from section one, automatically select another cell from another section.

**NOTE : I tried with setting the selection of the table view to multiple. but didn't work**

this is the link for the project in dropbox.
this is a simple project to test.

[click here to get the project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1p4r4mqyxn9dtba/AnuradhTest.zip?dl=0)

this is part of implementation

[image: part one image]
[image: part two image]

implementation code :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return 5;
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return 4;
    }
    else
    {
        return 20;
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(section == 0)
    {
        return @"SECTION 01";
    }
    else if(section == 1)
    {
        return @"SECTION 02";
    }
    else
    {
        return @"SECTION 03";
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    TestTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"mycell"];

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger sec = indexPath.section;
    NSInteger rw = indexPath.row;




    TestTableViewCell *cell = (TestTableViewCell *)[self.tablev cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.numberlabel.text = @"***";
    NSLog(@"selected section :%li ---> selected row :%li",(long)sec, (long)rw);

    [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;


    //in here I want fire the button acction in the cell for each row
}
```

hope your help with this.

Comment: Please provide relevant code in the body of the question itself, rather than providing a link. This way the answers would be potentially helpful not only to you, but also to other site visitors.

Comment: this is different @BhumitMehta

Comment: @bill Ok, I deleted the comment

Comment: @dasblinkenlight added the image, but working prototype explain the problem clearly

Comment: Wow, this is probably the highest-quality image of the program that I've seen on Stack Overflow to this date! Still, the problem with images is that they are not searchable from internet search engines, so a formatted text would be much better.

Comment: I think the problem with your code is that you never undo `cell.numberLabel.text = @"***"` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: once the cell gets the asterisks, the asterisks stay there forever, even when the cell has been reused through `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

Comment: added the code, sorry for the images, I can't preview those because images are blocked for users.sorry again @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @dasblinkenlight look at the accessory type after selecting the first row of the first section, there will be another cell in another section that automatically selected.

Comment: @bill Add `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;` before returning from `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @bill Cell will deque to reuse. So you need to keep track on selection of each row.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight not working , issue one:`if I select a cell, no it only select one cell, but if I scroll down and go back to up, check mark has disappeared` 
issue two:'`changes to the label affect for other rows in other sections`

Comment: @Mahesh how can I do it for this

Comment: @bill i'm giving answer on your old question as i'm not able to give answer here.

Comment: you need to maintain reusability like in array store value for label and checkbox and fill it in cellforRow then this reusability will maintained and this problem will not occure